# No crash logs but less than 100% stability

Tags: android, analytics, crashlytics, fabric.io

Looking at my latest release screen in fabric, I see a 98% stability.  If I drill down into it via "Investigate this release's top issues in Crashlytics." button, it doesn't provide any crash logs.  See the 2 attached screenshots.

I have the following in my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

repositories {
    maven {url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"}
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.15@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

[image: Latest Release]

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: May be crashes were found more than 7 days ago?

Comment: I see that some crash like native ones are not reported to crashlytics :/

Comment: This happens to me also on new releases. It's either the later screen is updated later or it doesn't reflect some crashes.

Comment: @VanyaSakharovskiy No this build is less than a week old

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here. Answers which powers the latest release dashboard knows in real-time that a session ended in a crash and can safely the couple hundred of bytes to our servers to process that data. While, on Android, we will try to send the crash after it has happened, we only guarantee sending it on relaunch of the app which is the most common reason why you won't see the crash yet in Crashlytics. The file is larger then an Answers event since there is much more data to include.

Comment: My app on Android uses a third party library that some times creates threads that crash but the library seems to be fine with that. Would those be reported as crashes by Answers? I see 20 times more crashes reported by Answers than Crashlytics and we have 10k daily active users. Does Answers grabs crash info from logcat?

Comment: It's a background thread because the debugger stops on the thread crash but you can continue execution after.